# Letters to Numbers with C++ chars

Tags: c++, char

Say I have a char extracted from a string ( str.at(i) ), how would I convert that char to a number such that A=0, B=1, C=2...  Z=25?  Thanx in advance

Comment: `int number = myChar - 'A';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the string is already in the `A-Z` range, you could do `char_value - 'A'`.

This assumes that the letters are all consecutive. So  `'B' == 'A' + 1`, `'C' == 'A' + 2`, etc.
In ASCII, this assumption is correct.

Comment: Yes this worked!  thank you!  If you could, can you explain why this works?

Comment: @BlakeDoeren Added some details. Hopefully, this should clarify things.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is probably the quickest response I've gotten on stack overflow yet.

Comment: @BlakeDoeren: with all those responses to your questions, be them quick or slow, would you mind to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one every now and then?

Answer (score 0):

Each Character has a specific ASCII code !!
Like A = 65 , b = 66 .. etc !!
If you simply subtract 65 or 'A' from each character , you will get the desired int

eg :

```
int a = charArray[i] - 65; 

if: charArray[i] = A
then: a = 0
```

& so on!!